# Invalid Column name when implementing search button

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm working with C# and SQL Sever 2008, when I try to create a command for searching a record I got exception that said "Invalid Column name"

this is my code :

```
void cari()
        {
            koneksi.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM jadwalkuliah where Subject = "+ textBox1.Text, koneksi);
            SDA.Fill(dt);
            koneksi.Close();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }`
```

the search command should be work as search engine, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't quoted the value of subject:

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM jadwalkuliah where Subject = '"+ textBox1.Text + "'",
```

koneksi);

Or for a *contains* search:
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM jadwalkuliah where Subject = '%"+ textBox1.Text + "%'", koneksi);

You shouldn't build queries this way. It is susceptible to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Great answer man, you're really helping me, thanks a lot! Btw i just need to make it more perfect by using keyword 'like'

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto: No, you *don't* just need to change it to use LIKE. You need to change it to use parameterized SQL. Don't take the shortcut here - do the job properly.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean by parameterized SQL? Could you explain me, because I'm a new guy in SQL.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto: Exactly what's in my answer... you express a parameter in the SQL itself, and then separately give a value for that parameter. It protects against SQL injection attacks, avoids unnecessary and potentially erroneous conversions, and separates your data from your code (SQL).

Comment: @JonSkeet Well now I get what you mean, so what should I do with your code that contains blank `using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))` what should I fill with for the blank space?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto: You should put in your connection information... which you'll already have somewhere. (This replaces your current use of `koneski`, which was also a problem. You should be opening/closing a new connection each time, and letting the connection pool make it efficient.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for helping me so far, but would you let me know why did you call my connection string which is called koneksi is a problem? Oh ya one more question, the blanks should be filled with my existing connection properties that I have define before right?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto: It's a problem because it looks like you're potentially sharing the same connection between many methods, which is a recipe for problems, particularly in a multi-threaded scenario. And yes, you should presumably be using the same connection properties as before.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I use the same connection when opening and closing database, FYI I build a WinForm application. Should I change my connection or what because I really don't know about multi-thread that you mean.

Answer (score 5):

Well the *immediate* problem is that your WHERE clause will look something like:

```
where Subject = Foo
```

which is trying to compare the value of the Subject column with the value of the Foo column.

The *hacky* way of fixing this is to put quotes round the value. The *better* solution is to use parameterized SQL:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM jadwalkuliah where Subject = @Subject";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                                    .Value = textBox1.Text;
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
```

Additionally, note that you shouldn't be performing database accesses from a GUI thread. It's not clear whether this is a web app (in which case it's okay) or WPF/WinForms (in which case it's not).

Note that that will still try to make an *exact* match. For a "wildcard" match you'll need to change it to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM jadwalkuliah where Subject LIKE @Subject
```

... and add the parameter with something like `"%" + textBox1.Text + "%"`. (You'll need to then think about escaping within that value, but that's another matter...)

Comment: Why is it more "ok" to query the DB directly from a web app than it is from a winforms app? I think this strongly depends on the scale and architecture of the app, not the type of presentation.

Comment: @flem: It's not about the "directly" part - it's about threading. In a rich client scenario, you'd be blocking the UI thread, and therefore freezing the app. In a web app you'd be just blocking the response from being sent - which is fine, as you really can't return the response until you've got the data...